# Jenkins Bitbucket Team/Project job doesn't fetch tags anymore

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins Bitbucket Team/Project job.
Inside the Jenkinsfile in my repository I use "git describe" to get the current tag.
After I updated to the latest Jenkins version (2.60.3) and updated most plugins, this fails because Jenkins doesn't fetch tags anymore.

This is what I had before the update:

```
Branch event
Checking out git https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxxx to read Jenkinsfile
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/xxxx.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Admin user to clone bitbucket repositories
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx.git +refs/heads/master
```

This is what I have now:

```
Branch event
Checking out git https://bitbucket.org/xxxx.git into /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xxxx/jobs/xxx/branches/master/workspace@script to read Jenkinsfile
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/xxx/jobs/xxxx/branches/master/workspace@script # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/xxx.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Admin user to clone bitbucket repositories
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/xxxx.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This is the plugins I have installed:

- Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin 2.2.3
- Bitbucket Plugin 1.1.5
- Git Client plugin 2.5.0
- Git plugin 3.5.1

The default behaviour changed. It's not fetching tags anymore (uses --no-tags).
I couldn't find any settings to force jenkins to fetch tags.
In Bitbucket Team/Project settings, you can setup "Advanced clone behaviours":

- Shallow clone
- ...
- Do not fetch tags

"Do not fetch tags" is not selected. So I'd think that it should fetch tags by default...

Anyone having similar issue?
How can I force Jenkins to fetch tags in a Bitbucket Team/Project job?

Comment: Same problem for me !

Comment: I've seen you reported a bug in Bitbucket plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46736?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20bitbucket-branch-source-plugin%20AND%20text%20~%20%22tags%22. Do you have a workaround ? As we are using jgitver plugin, fetching tags is mandatory for my project. I had to rollback to the previous version of the plugin.

Comment: The workaround I use right now, is to fetch tags manually in my job... I run `sh 'git fetch --tags'` in the first step of my Jenkinsfile. But that's kind of ugly and I can't initialise variables that depends on tags in the environment section (in declarative mode)...

Comment: Hi @BenjaminBertrand, looks like you had the same idea. But I ran into the following issue: `+ git fetch --tags.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address`. How did you solve the credentials/auth issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a Jenkins issue and got some explanations (thanks to Stephen Connolly): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46736

The solution is just to add the "Advanced Clone Behaviours" and to leave "Do not fetch tags" unchecked.